# How can I transfer files to a host and pass password to it

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to copy some files from gitlab ci to my host. I'm currently using `open-sshclient` with scp but its throwing an error:

> user@ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).

I don't know how to pass the password to the script.

Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: node:9.6.1

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - build/
    - docker-compose.yml
    - Dockerfile
    - nginx.conf

stages:
  - build
  - dockerize

build-stage:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - CI=false npm run build
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - build/
      - docker-compose.yml
      - nginx.conf

dockerize-stage:
  stage: dockerize
  image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  dependencies:
    - build-stage
  tags:
    - docker  
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add --no-cache openssh-client
    - mkdir ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - echo "${USER_PASS}" || ssh-add -
    - ssh -p22 user@ip "mkdir /home/test"
    - scp -P22 -r build/* user@ip:/home/test
```

While this is the output from gitlab ci:

```
$ apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.8.4-9-g931e9aefbb [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main]
v3.8.4-4-gc27a9a0149 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community]
OK: 9550 distinct packages available
$ apk add --no-cache openssh-client
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing openssh-keygen (7.7_p1-r4)
(2/2) Installing openssh-client (7.7_p1-r4)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger
OK: 67 MiB in 28 packages
$ mkdir ~/.ssh
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 20
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ echo "${USER_PASS}" || ssh-add -
"IT SHOWS THE PASSWORD"
$ ssh -p22 user@ip "mkdir /home/test"
Warning: Permanently added 'ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
user@ip: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I dont know if I need to add a publickey too or only the password. And if so how can I do it?

Or is there any other way to send files to another server by providing password

Answer (score 1):

Add your password to Gitlab secret variable, for example - DEPLOY_SSH_PASSWORD (somewhere in settings of the project) and use it:

```
sshpass -p $DEPLOY_SSH_PASSWORD ssh user@ip
```

But I suggest you to use private keys, it is more secure.
Add your private key to Gitlab secret variable, for example - DEPLOY_SSH_KEY, copy private key to temporary file on the runner:

```
- echo "$DEPLOY_SSH_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And just use it:

```
- ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@ip
```

Comment: Secret variables are located here: Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Environment variables

Comment: now its saying: `$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@ip`
`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`
`Host key verification failed.`

Comment: I generated rsa in my host by `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and its saved as `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` under `~/.ssh`. And i put the content of `id_rsa.pub` in environment variable

Comment: You need to put private part of the key to variables, i.g. file `id_rsa`

Comment: @QuasWex I also tried to add `id_rsa` content too env variable but still the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the private key of the server

```
scp -C -i <link to your private key> -r <source_directory> username@ip:<target_directory>
```

If you just want to ssh

```
ssh -i <link to your private key> username@ip
```

Comment: Both of them showing: `Host key verification failed.` I generated rsa in my host by ssh-keygen -t rsa and its saved as id_rsa and id_rsa.pub under ~/.ssh. And i put the content of id_rsa.pub in environment variable